# Postgres regexp replace not working

Tags: regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

Im trying to create a regexp for this query:

```
SELECT gruppo
FROM righe_conto_ready
WHERE regexp_replace(gruppo,'(\[{1})|(\].*?\[)|(\].*$)','','g') = '[U6][U53]'
LIMIT 10
```

This is an example of 'gruppo' column:

```
[U6]  CAFFETTERIA   [U43]  THE E TISANE
```

Im currently using this query for testing:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(gruppo,'(\[{1})|(\].*?\[)|(\].*$)','','g') FROM ....
```

and it returns just `U6`

How can i change the regexp to remove everything outside brackets?

Comment: What is outside brackets?

Comment: Try `'\[|\][^][]*\[|\][^][]*$'` regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_matches()` with the much simpler regular expression:

```
with righe_conto_ready(gruppo) as (
    select '[U6]  CAFFETTERIA   [U43]  THE E TISANE'::text
)

select gruppo
from righe_conto_ready, 
lateral regexp_matches(gruppo, '\[.+?\]', 'g') matches
group by 1
having string_agg(matches[1], '') = '[U6][U43]'

                 gruppo                  
-----------------------------------------
 [U6]  CAFFETTERIA   [U43]  THE E TISANE
(1 row)
```

When you are looking for multiple matches of some pattern, `regexp_matches()` seems more natural than `regexp_replace()`.

You can also search for first two substrings in brackets (without the `g` flag the function yields no more than one row):

```
select gruppo
from righe_conto_ready, 
lateral regexp_matches(gruppo, '(\[.+?\]).*(\[.+?\])') matches
where concat(matches[1], matches[2]) = '[U6][U43]'
```

Comment: This helped me... Thanks!